# Xtext: using the grammar classes in ISemanticHighlightingCalculator

Tags: syntax-highlighting, xtext

Listen, I have a grammar. See just the specific part I need to handle:

```
Par:
    id=ID | string=STRING | integer=INT;
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
if it's a Par element of type ID then color the background
if it's a Par element of type STRING then set text color
```

And here is my *SemanticHighlightingCalculator*

```
public class GrailSemanticHighlightingCalculator implements ISemanticHighlightingCalculator {

    @Override
    public void provideHighlightingFor(XtextResource resource, IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor) {
        if (resource == null) return;

        Iterable<AbstractNode> allNodes = NodeUtil.getAllContents( resource.getParseResult().getRootNode() );
            for (AbstractNode node : allNodes) {
                System.out.println(node.getGrammarElement().toString());
                if (node.getGrammarElement() instanceof Par) {
                    System.out.println("Il mio par: " + ((Par)node).getId());
                    acceptor.addPosition(node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), GrailHighlightingConfiguration.ELEMENT_ID);
                }
              }
    }

}
```

I'm doing this as written here in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/1_0_1/xtext.html#highlighting). I'm not getting any error at compile time. Here's an example output of `System.out.println(node.getGrammarElement().toString());`

```
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@165a43b (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@159b3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@a866a9 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@f4c9c4 (cardinality: null) (value: ()
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@a82a10 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@618b08 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1da2b6d (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@591171 (cardinality: null) (value: ,)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1882876 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@618b08 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1da2b6d (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@591171 (cardinality: null) (value: ,)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1882876 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@618b08 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1860e4 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@ea8847 (cardinality: null) (value: ))
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@812517 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@aa3e9a (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f42d53 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@cbb612 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1990d96 (cardinality: null) (value: ()
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e7f21 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.ActionImpl@2c79a5 (cardinality: null) (feature: left, operator: =)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@aa3e9a (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f42d53 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@cbb612 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1990d96 (cardinality: null) (value: ()
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e7f21 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@aa3e9a (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f42d53 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@cbb612 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e668c2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1e7a4d0 (cardinality: null) (value: .)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f55ff2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@16e3eb3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@d67d61 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1860e4 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@14afef4 (cardinality: null) (value: ))
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1c190a2 (cardinality: null) (value: AND)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@feba21 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@16dd645 (cardinality: null) (value: NOT)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@e54f3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e668c2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1e7a4d0 (cardinality: null) (value: .)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f55ff2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@16e3eb3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@d67d61 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@eb3f66 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@14afef4 (cardinality: null) (value: ))
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@165a43b (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@159b3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@a866a9 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@f4c9c4 (cardinality: null) (value: ()
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@a82a10 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@618b08 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1da2b6d (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@ea8847 (cardinality: null) (value: ))
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@812517 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@aa3e9a (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f42d53 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@cbb612 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1990d96 (cardinality: null) (value: ()
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e7f21 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@aa3e9a (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f42d53 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@cbb612 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1e668c2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@1e7a4d0 (cardinality: null) (value: .)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@f55ff2 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@16e3eb3 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@d67d61 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.TerminalRuleImpl@1eed0fb (name: WS)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@1860e4 (cardinality: null)
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl@14afef4 (cardinality: null) (value: ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only just starting out with XText as well but I might be able to help. I was able to get syntax highlighting working for a small project with similar code to yours, but with a few differences. I found the useful forum posting [on the Eclipse forums here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.modeling.tmf/msg01226.html).

Based on the console output it looks like it's never recognising any of the AbstractNodes as being an instance of Par.

The differences between the Eclipse forum and your code seem to be:

- It uses `Iterator<EObject> iter = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(resource, true);` and a `while` loop to iterate through the results.
- It checks the type (in your case for Par) against the EObject directly rather than using `getGrammarElement`.

It might be as simple as changing it as above, to something like:

```
public class GrailSemanticHighlightingCalculator implements ISemanticHighlightingCalculator {

@Override
public void provideHighlightingFor(XtextResource resource, IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor) {
    if (resource == null) return;

    Iterator<EObject> iter = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(resource, true);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        EObject current = iter.next();
        if (current instanceof Par) {
            Par parNode = (Par) current;
            if (parNode.getId() != null) {
                acceptor.addPosition(node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), GrailHighlightingConfiguration.ELEMENT_ID);
            } else if (parNode.getString() != null) {
                acceptor.addPosition(node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), GrailHighlightingConfiguration.ELEMENT_STRING);
            } else if (parNode.getInt() != null) {
                acceptor.addPosition(node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), GrailHighlightingConfiguration.ELEMENT_INT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've included some code to handle the other highlighting options, so you'd need to add in the ELEMENT_STRING and ELEMENT_INT handlers to your `configure()` method in whatever your IHighlightingConfiguration class is called, to return the `TextStyle` applicable to them.

Also note that I have not tested any of the above, so it may actually be completely wrong and misleading! Hope it's not, though. :)

Comment: tnx pal, I've used EcoreUtil :)

Answer (score 2):

For Xtext 2.0, this code can be used as a template:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EStructuralFeature;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.ILeafNode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.INode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.syntaxcoloring.IHighlightedPositionAcceptor;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.syntaxcoloring.ISemanticHighlightingCalculator;

public class YourDslSemanticHighlightingCalculator implements ISemanticHighlightingCalculator {

    @Override
    public void provideHighlightingFor( XtextResource resource, IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor ) {
        if( resource == null ) {
            return;
        }

        HighlightingSwitch switcher = new HighlightingSwitch( acceptor );

        Iterator<EObject> iter = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(resource, true);
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            EObject current = iter.next();

            switcher.doSwitch( current );
        }
    }

    private class HighlightingSwitch extends YourDslSwitch<Void> {

        private final IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor;

        public HighlightingSwitch( IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor ) {
            this.acceptor = acceptor;
        }

        @Override
        public Void caseOption( Option object ) {
            INode node = getFirstFeatureNode( object, YourDslPackage.eINSTANCE.getOption_Name() );
            highlightNode( node, YourDslHighlightingConfiguration.OPTION );
            return null;
        }

        private void highlightNode( INode node, String id ) {
            if( node == null )
                return;
            if( node instanceof ILeafNode ) {
                acceptor.addPosition( node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), id );
            } else {
                for( ILeafNode leaf : node.getLeafNodes() ) {
                    if( !leaf.isHidden() ) {
                        acceptor.addPosition( leaf.getOffset(), leaf.getLength(), id );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public INode getFirstFeatureNode( EObject semantic, EStructuralFeature feature ) {
        if( feature == null )
            return NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor( semantic );
        List<INode> nodes = NodeModelUtils.findNodesForFeature( semantic, feature );
        if( !nodes.isEmpty() )
            return nodes.get( 0 );
        return null;
    }    

}
```

This iterates over all nodes in your model and invokes a case in the `HighlightingSwitch`.

In the case method, you need to locate the `INode` related to the feature or `EObject` instance that you care about and then, you can highlight it.

Note that `getFirstFeatureNode()` doesn't search the whole AST for a node; the implementation is actually pretty fast.

The style configuration looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.syntaxcoloring.DefaultHighlightingConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.syntaxcoloring.IHighlightingConfigurationAcceptor;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.utils.TextStyle;

public class YourDslHighlightingConfiguration extends DefaultHighlightingConfiguration {

    public static final String OPTION = "yourDsl.option";

    public void configure(IHighlightingConfigurationAcceptor acceptor) {

        acceptor.acceptDefaultHighlighting( OPTION, "Option", option() );

        super.configure( acceptor );
    }

    public TextStyle option() {
        TextStyle textStyle = defaultTextStyle().copy();
        textStyle.setColor( new RGB( 0, 26, 171 ) );
        textStyle.setStyle( SWT.ITALIC );
        return textStyle;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to bind the two new classes in your UI module!